# Create charts for a facebook page via open graph and php

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-insights

I have created a FB App that grants the following permissions from the user:
1. manage_pages
2. read_insights

By using the app, the user can create a new tab on a page and delete it when this is necessary. 
Apart from that, I want to give the option to the user to see some basic stats regarding the page(s) that she creates the tab(s).

For example, I want to retrieve the page views for a certain page for a specific period.
In order to do this I used the following code:

```
$today  = date("Y-m-d");
$until  = strtotime($today);
$since  = strtotime("2013-08-01");
$pageID = "123";

$page_info    = $facebook->api("/$pageID?fields=access_token");
$access_token = $page_info['access_token'];

$params = array(
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'since' => $since, 
        'until' => $until, 
      );


$insights = $facebook->api("/{$pageID}/insights/page_views/", 
            "GET",
            $params
           );
print_r($insights);
```

The problem is that the result is...somehow empty. More precisely, I receive the following:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
        )
    [paging] => Array
    (
 [previous]=>https://graph.facebook.com/123/insights/page_views/since=1370059200&until=1375329600
     [next]=>https://graph.facebook.com/123/insights/page_views/since=1380600000&until=1385870400
    )
)
```

When I use, the same logic to receive insights for my app (without using $token in the $params array), I receive the right data.

In addition to that, I was wondering if there is a way to create charts with this data (directly from FB).

Thx,
Antonis

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem.
The returning array was empty, because I forgot to check if the user is logged in through facebook...

Regarding the charts, I didn't find any solution directly from facebook, so I used the [Charts.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) plugin.

Comment: Mind sharing the code you use to enter the data into the chart.js plugin dynamically?